# Установка программы требует обновления, а обновления рушат установленные программы. Как быть?

Tags: windows-7, обновления, visual-studio-2015

У меня *windows-7 x64*. Сборка.

Мне необходимо установить *Microsoft visual studio 2015* (ну и в придачу IE10, т.к. установщик очень просит его).

Но для корректной работы *VS 2015* (как я понял..но это не факт) Майкрософту необходимо сделать некие обновления. Эти самые обновления сразу после установки VS - винда сама перезагружается скачивает и устанавливает (видимо в установщике прописано)

Но, к сожалению, после этих обновлений перестают работать многие программы. Выдают ошибку `0xc0000005` и подобного типа. Не запускаются.

В инете решение этой проблемы только одно - откат системы.

В итоге порочный круг. Нужна *VS* - она лезет за обновлениями - убиваются другие программы. Снос обновления - все работает - но *VS* не работает

Вопрос: можно ли все же как-то поставить этот *VS* без обновлений, убивающих систему? Например? узнать какое конкретное обновление такое может сделать и конкретно его потом снести, при этом оставив *VS* работающим.

Или без сноса винды с первоначальным накатом обновлением тут не обойтись?

Comment: Назови программы, которые крашатся после обновления?

Comment: Программы должны работать несмотря на обновления. Если программа после обновления не работает — это её баг. В качестве воркэраунда, поставьте что-то одно на VirtualPC или аналог.

Comment: @ bukashka101 их много. total commander, live reload, дрова звуковухи, cubase и пр. Но как пишут в инете - крэшатся 32-битные проги, по неким причинам

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я ответил на вопрос и о программах, и о Visual Studio.

Comment: @VladD это может быть еще и баг фреймворка. Где-то на хабре была статья, в которой описывалось как установка .NET 4.6 ломает работу всех приложений на .NET 4.5. Эту ошибку давно уже исправили (надеюсь) - но такая возможность все равно существует. Так что утверждение "программы должны работать несмотря на обновления" неверно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: В любом случае, это чей-то баг. :-\ Так быть не должно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov это был баг с tail call, и его давным-давно починили.

Answer (score 0):

Я столкнулся с этой проблемой уже после того как моя Windows 7 x64 накрылась по другим причинам. Я работал на Visual Studio 2013. Я не стал обновлять старую версию до уровня 2015, а просто установил рядом Visual Studio Comunity 2015. В итоге на ноуте именно так сейчас и работает. Ошибка не возникает. За стабильную работу системы не ручаюсь, но как решение - возможно.

Comment: Так я и не обновлял старую версию, я пытался установить 2015, который в свою очередь требовал некие системные обновления, которые в свою очередь сломали 64-битные программы. Так что ничего не помогло. Вам видимо как-то повезло.)

Comment: Мне подсказали) дело в том что у меня на ноуте процессор AMD и кое-какие установки для работы OS Windows 7 x64 SP1 не требовались.

Answer (score -2):

Вынужден Вас огорчить, но вряд ли у Вас выйдет установить Visual Studio 2015 без танцев с бубном. **Visual Studio 2015 корректно устанавливается начиная от Windows 8.1** (посмотрел в системных требованиях)**, кроме Visual Studio Express**.

Для Вас есть два решения проблемы:

1. Устанавливаете более старую версию (если честно, я не заметил отличий).
2. Качаете чистую Windows 10 (желательно ISO образ с сайта Microsoft), устанавливаете полностью все форматирую, так как установка\обновление поверх Windows 7 с сохранением данных чревата ошибками, а потом ставите на него Visual Studio 2015.
3. Ставите Visual Studio Express. Функционал урезан (но я, опять же, не заметил), но работает на Windows 7.

P.S. Лучше установите Windows 10, так как многие программы "отключаются" Microsoft`ом от Windows 7 и переделываются для Windows 10.

А ошибки, скорее всего, потому что у Вас отключается поддержка х32 разрядных приложений (не знаю почему, но у меня была такая фигня на ломаной Windows 7 и помог только снос обновлений). С этим помогут [тут](http://chingachgook.net/serv/windows-7-ne-zapuskayutsya-programmy-oshibka-0xc0000005.html)

Comment: Вроде ж нет: https://www.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs

Comment: @VladD, я тут смотрел — https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx

Comment: @VladD, ой! Visul Studio Express пашет под 7кой.

Comment: @bukashka101 да снос обновлений я итак знаю. делал..... 10-ку ставить не хочу ибо ОООООЧЕНЬ много  программ (несколько десятков и занимаемые под пол терабайта) установлены и переустанавливать заново как-то не очень хочется.... Попробую express посмотрю, что выйдет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, разбейте жесткий диск на два раздела, на один закиньте программы, а на другой ставьте систему. Только не перепутайте! ..как я :D.

Comment: Точно, ставьте windows 10, как же вы раньше жили без рекламы в меню Пуск.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если вы не пользовались Windows 10 — не нужно тут рассказывать, что он плохой. У меня стоит 10ка и никакой рекламы, все работает хорошо и быстрее, чем на Win 7.

Comment: @bukashka101 Так у меня программы стоят на другом жестком диске, а не на диске `C`. Пол террабайта. а вся регистрация в реестре висит. А при переходе на 10 надо бы лучше все снести нежели накатывать. А это ужас.

Comment: P.S.... Так.... Испробовал.  VS Express for Desktop установился без проблем без всякий скачиваний обновлений на win-7 x64. На сколько он отличен от других версий не знаю. Посмотрю. Но установился - факт. Гут!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, лезть в дебри разработки — Вас вполне хватит и Express`a.